# C++11 RegEx, non-greedy

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, non-greedy

I have a little bit of a problem with a C++11 RegEx and I think it is about greedynes.

Here is a little sample.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main (void)
{
  std::string in="{ab}{cd}[ef]{gh}[ij][kl]";  // the input-string

  std::regex rx1 ("(\\{.+?})(.*)", std::regex::extended);       // non-greedy?
  std::smatch match;

  if (regex_match (in, match, rx1))
  {
    printf ("\n%s\n", match.str(1).c_str());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I would expect

```
{ab}
```

for output.
But I got

```
{ab}{cd}[ef]{gh}
```

I would expect the result I get, if I do it greedy but not with the ? after the .+.
Should make it non-greedy, right?

So whats the problem in my idea?
Thanks for help!

Chris

Comment: Why do you escape the opening curly brace with `\\{` but you do not escape the closing curly brace?

Comment: @Bobulous that's a regex special char which helps to repeat the previous pattern..

Comment: I think you should not use `std::regex::extended`, it makes your regex POSIX ERE compliant, that does not support lazy quantifiers.

Comment: Ah, okay, the opening brace is considered a special character by regex, but a closing brace is not. Did not know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the [`std::regex::extended`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type), it makes your regex [POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) compliant, and that regex flavor does not support lazy quantifiers.

```
std::regex rx1("(\\{.+?})(.*)");
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/ysHmLB)